# account/list_of_post_by_subactegory.html TemplateDoesNotExist

Tags: python, django

I can't solve this problem. When you try to load the page, **list_of_post_by_subcategory.html** throws `TemplatesDoesNotExist`, Please help.

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('list_of_post_by_category', args=[self.slug])

class SubCategory(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, related_name="subcategories")
    subcategory = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.subcategory

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('list_of_post_by_subcategory', args=[self.slug])
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^category/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.list_of_post_by_category, name= 'list_of_post_by_category'),
url(r'^subcategory/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.list_of_post_by_subcategory, name= 'list_of_post_by_subcategory'),
```

views.py

```
def list_of_post_by_category(request, slug):
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    category=get_object_or_404(Category, slug = slug)
    subcategories = SubCategory.objects.filter(category=category)
    posts = Post.objects.filter(category=category)
    return render(request, "account/list_of_post_by_category.html", {'categories': categories, 'posts': posts, 'category': category, 'subcategories': subcategories})

def list_of_post_by_subcategory(request, slug):
    subcategory=get_object_or_404(SubCategory, slug=slug)
    posts = Post.objects.filter(subcategory=subcategory)
    return render(request, "account/list_of_post_by_subcategory.html", {'posts': posts, 'subcategory': subcategory})
```

list_of_post_by_subcategory.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}{{ subcategory.subcategory }}{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<h1>{{ subcategory.subcategory }}</h1>
{% for post in posts %}
<div class="single_post">
   <a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
<br/>
<br/>
   <div>
       {{ post.publish }}
                                 {{ post.subcategory }}
</div>
</div>
 {% endfor %}
<br/>
{% endblock %}
```

Similar template **list_of_post_by_category.html** loads correctly. But **list_of_post_by_subcategory.html** throws `TemplateDoesNotExist`.

Comment: you've checked and double-checked the filename? That's the only way you can get a TemplateDoesNotExist, if the file doesn't exist.

Comment: Can you share the full error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filenames don't match here. You posted your error as `account/list_of_post_by_subactegory.html TemplateDoesNotExist` Look at the name of html file you mentioned(**subactegory**). And the one you are calling has this name `account/list_of_post_by_subcategory.html`